# Gitlab running stages in docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am new to GitLab and I am trying to set up CI pipeline where I want to run and terraform scripts from inside the docker image just to make sure I have all the necessary base images already installed and built.

Currently the CI pipeline I came up with some investigation on official docs looks something like this:

```
 stages:
  - terraform:check

.base-terraform:
  image:
    name: "hashicorp/terraform"
    entrypoint: [""]

  before_script:
    - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
    - terraform version

tf-fmt:
  stage: terraform:check
  extends: .base-terraform
  script:
    - make fmt
  needs: []
```

With the above YAML file, it downloads the latest version of Terraform(>=0.15) which I don't want, and plus I need other dependencies like `make` etc etc. So I was thinking if there is any way where I can build my own custom image use that as extends in stages so that all the necessary dependencies are available for the CI/CD to run.

My DockerFile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev unzip wget

RUN wget -O terraform.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.13.0/terraform_0.13.0_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip terraform.zip  && \
    mv terraform /usr/local/bin/

RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.17.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && \
    chmod +x ./kubectl &&  \
    mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .
```

Am I thinking in the right direction? Or is there a much simpler way in gitlab? I have accomplished such tasks with buildkite as I was using buildkite as my CI tool in my past experience.

Comment: I did the same building my own CI image, so I would say it's the right direction. If you want to avoid having the last terraform version using the official image, you can point to a docker tag for [0.13 version](https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/terraform/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=0.13) specifically.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster thanks for the suggestion. I was wondering if you just let me know the steps to build and use the custom image that would be awesome as official docs arent helping much

Comment: I did like you, installing every tools I need in a docker image starting from a light image. Then, once the image is built, your can refer it under `image` > `name` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: I am able to build the image but when I pass it under `image` > `name` in my yml file, its failing with `pull access denied for evdp-ci, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`. When the image is already available why its trying to pull from docker hub?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. On my side, after the build, I pushed the image on gitlab internal registry. So you need to refer it `image > name` using the gitlab registry name or change the default behavior at runner [level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-an-image).

Comment: @NicolasPepinster thanks man, now I got the lightest image to run in CI with all the dependencies I need. I just used the private GitLab registry and as the image was so light the option can place it in artifact and pull it from there in other steps. Anyways thanks :)